# document.click without one div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<table id="tab">
    <tr><td class="click" id="111">111</td> <td id="222" class="click">222</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="click" id="333">333</td> <td id="444" class="click">444</td></tr>
</table>

<div id="hidden" class="ooo">
   text
</div>


#tab tr td {
padding: 10px;
    border: solid 1px red;
}

#hidden {
    background-color:green;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    display: none;
}

$(".click").click(function(e){
    $("#hidden").show();
    $("#hidden").offset({top: $(this).offset().top, left: $(this).offset().left+10});
    e.stopPropagation();
})
$(document).click(function() {
    $('#hidden').hide();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QyRnH/9/

Is possible disable #hidden if i click on #hidden? :) I would like hide div hidden only if click outside #hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can detect which element was clicked exactly in your `$(document).click` function by checking the `event.target`. So you can just compare its `id` and make sure it's not `#hidden`.

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
    if (event.target.id != 'hidden') {
       $('#hidden').hide();  
    }
});
```

Here is your updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/QyRnH/15/

Answer (score 3):

The answer is already in your code. Basically, you want to stop the click event on your `#hidden` div from bubbling up to the document element:

```
$("#hidden").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    // do stuff

});
```

- http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/